# Set connections in excel to default to read

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, microsoft-excel-2016, read-only, connection-sharing

As I've create connections in Excel via,

- Data Menu
- Get External Data
- MS Access from Ribbon

The connection that gets created by default is of `Mode=Share Deny Write`.

I know I can manually change the connection string from the property menu, but is there a way to change the default behavior of MS Excel (MS Office Professional Plus 2016) to default to `Mode=READ` ?

I need this to be the standard for other colleagues to connect to a shared DB.

Ideally the solution would not require Admin privileges, since I only have standard user access.

Answer (score 1):

**Shared, Deny Write** , already means Read enabled.

But only if other users have permissions to access the folder such as in the shared folder for that group or all users.

Comment: I need to avoid the "Deny Write" part, as people may be connected to the back end database while I need to update. I don't mind if that creates issues to the users in terms of inconsistency, but due to business needs, I need to be able to clear and append the data that the other users may be connected to

Comment: The MSOffice method of Notifying users of updates is not clear to me. From my experience, there was never a notify active readers of updates feature, because the server can not tell which shared clients are active or need updates.  This is why people who use MSOffice use Access because of the *.MDB file is live or use the equiv. SQL database etc.  I hope there is a share "push notification" for you.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, maybe in giving context I diverted attention from core question. 

All I want to do is change the default behavior of excel in creating a connection from "Share Deny Write" to "Read".

Does anyone know how to do this?
Is there a registry key that needs to be change, a setting in Excel, an option that can be changed? 

 Is it even possible? 

Thanks Sunnyskyguy

Comment: Are you sure that is an option?